# Play, Amazon S3 create bucket call authorization header is malformed wrong region when correctly specified

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, playframework-2.0

I am using the Play framework 2.5 and aws-java-sdk version 1.11.12. I am making a call to create an S3 bucket for a particular region and am getting an error that I do not understand. It tells me that the region is wrong and should be us-west-2, even though that is what I am passing to the createBucket call. Can someone please help?

```
@Inject
public AmazonS3ComponentImpl(Configuration configuration) {
  String accessKey = configuration.getString(AWS_ACCESS_KEY);
  String secretKey = configuration.getString(AWS_SECRET_KEY);
  amazonS3Bucket = configuration.getString(AWS_S3_BUCKET);

  if ((accessKey != null) && (secretKey != null)) {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);

    try {
      amazonS3.createBucket(amazonS3Bucket, Region.US_West_2);
    } catch (AmazonS3Exception e) {
      if (e.getErrorCode().compareTo("BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou") != 0
        && e.getErrorCode().compareTo("AccessDenied") != 0) {
        throw e;
      }
    } finally {
      Logger.info("Using bucket " + amazonS3Bucket);
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2' (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed; Request ID: 261B779D23D15F6F)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:919)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:449)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:411)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:360)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3962)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:908)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:855)
at com.zently.modules.AmazonS3ComponentImpl.<init>(AmazonS3Component.java:42)
```

Comment: Have you tried [`amazonS3.setRegion`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-region-selection.html) to set the region used by the actual client object?  The error refers not to the bucket attribute, but to the authorization headers sent with the request, which default to us-east-1.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following line of code right after creating the new AmazonS3Client did the trick.

```
amazonS3.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may come if the bucket name is already existing in the given region. Try giving some other bucket name eg "yournamebucket" that is usually unique. I tried this way and it worked for me.